# Perl Carp:confess unit test

Tags: perl, unit-testing, carp

I am trying to write a perl unit test. I am able to test happy-case scenario for it. However if there is an error generated in the method it prints the error using `Carp:confess "<message>"`. I am not able to catch this case in my test. 
I tried using

`dies_ok( <method call>, 'Expected Error' );`

However the test case still fails.  It prints the message passed to Carp::confess and then prints

`Looks like your test exited with 111 before it could output anything. Dubious, test returned 111 (wstat 28416, 0x6f00)`

Is there a way I can catch this? I even tried `throws_ok` but not working.

Please assist by guiding how I should catch these errors. Am I using these `dies_ok` and `throws_ok` incorrectly ?

Comment: did you wrap the method call in an anonymous sub?

Comment: No I hadn't... I did that and it worked...Can you please explain why a anonymous sub is required to be encapsulating the call? I am not clear on that...
Also can you please post the explanation as answer so I can accept it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may just check $@ after eval expression.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

use Carp qw(confess);

sub err { confess('Bad thing'); }

eval { err };
like($@, qr/^Bad thing/, "confess('Bad thing')");

done_testing();
```